# Updated Oracle ADF libraries on tomcat server produces an error

Tags: tomcat, oracle11g, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic-10.x

I have a simple Oracle ADF application developed using jDeveloper IDE. By default, the WAR file generated from jDeveloper (in ADF applications) runs on WebLogic server. However, my requirement is to make this same application run on TomCat 6.0. I followed the steps described in [this document](http://www.lorman.sk/pages/java/adf/ADFTomcatDemo.pdf) and successfully made the Oracle ADF application run on TomCat Server 6. Basically you have to copy all the libs to WEB-INF/lib and do some XML config changes here and there.

However there is another issue in ADF apps as they don't support IE11. [Oracle have patched](https://blogs.oracle.com/proactivejavadevelopment/entry/supportability_on_internet_explorer_11) this issue and my plan was to replace the libraries in side Tomcat's lib folder with the patched jar files. Here is the list of jar files which got replaced.

- adf-richclient-api-11.jar
- adf-richclient-impl-11.jar
- dvt-faces.jar
- trinidad-api.jar
- trinidad-impl.jar

However when I start the tomcat catalina log contains following error stack.

```
SEVERE: buildComponentConfigList
oracle.mds.config.MDSConfigurationException: MDS-01329: unable to load element "{http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config}mds-component-config"    
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.
    at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils.getBeanFromElement(ConfigurationUtils.java:244)
    at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.loadFromElement(MDSComponentConfig.java:332)
    at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.<init>(MDSComponentConfig.java:488)
    at oracle.mds.config.MDSComponentConfig.getMDSComponentConfigList(MDSComponentConfig.java:168)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.buildComponentConfigList(ADFMDSConfig.java:77)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.getDefaultMDSInstance(ADFMDSConfig.java:446)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:64)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.FallbackConfigImpl.getDefaultMDSInstance(FallbackConfigImpl.java:95)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:648)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFConfigImpl.java:628)
    at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.getMDSInstance(ADFContextMDSConfigHelperImpl.java:274)
    at oracle.adf.share.ADFContext.getMDSInstanceAsObject(ADFContext.java:1757)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initialize(ServletADFContext.java:494)
    at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFContext.initThreadContext(ServletADFContext.java:401)
    at oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:317)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:288)
    at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils$1.run(ConfigurationUtils.java:207)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.mds.internal.config.ConfigurationUtils.getBeanFromElement(ConfigurationUtils.java:202)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'audit-config'. One of '{"http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":file-type-config, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":event-notification, "http://xmlns.oracle.com/mds/config":untyped-dependency-config}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:417)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1806)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:705)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:228)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:265)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:305)
    ... 46 more
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: ADFConnection mbean not registered for defaultApplicationName. 
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: 
oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
    at oracle.jrf.ServerPlatformSupportFactory.getInstance(ServerPlatformSupportFactory.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.mbean.share.connection.ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConnectionLifeCycleCallBack.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: Failed to register config mbean for defaultApplicationName.
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: 
oracle.jrf.UnknownPlatformException: JRF is unable to determine the current application server platform.
    at oracle.jrf.ServerPlatformSupportFactory.getInstance(ServerPlatformSupportFactory.java:79)
    at oracle.adf.mbean.share.config.ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(ADFConfigLifeCycleCallBack.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
SEVERE: Not able to get Deployment Name
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack contextInitialized
WARNING: MDS-01702: The method getBean() is not valid for metadata object /demo/fusion/model/common/bc4j.xcfg - it is allowed on only bean metadata objects.
oracle.mds.exception.MDSRuntimeException: MDS-01702: The method getBean() is not valid for metadata object /demo/fusion/model/common/bc4j.xcfg - it is allowed on only bean metadata objects.
    at oracle.mds.core.MetadataObject.getBean(MetadataObject.java:327)
    at oracle.adf.share.jndi.MDSBackingStore.getMOBean(MDSBackingStore.java:558)
    at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.init(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:120)
    at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.<init>(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:110)
    at oracle.bc4j.mbean.RuntimeMXBeanImpl.<init>(RuntimeMXBeanImpl.java:101)
    at oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack.contextInitialized(BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:10 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.1 ( 20130709-1453 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.1@12065) for context '/ADFMinimal_ViewController_webapp1'
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.<init>(UnifiedRenderKit.java:129)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKit.createRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKit.java:113)
    at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.unified.renderkit.UnifiedRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(UnifiedRenderKitFactory.java:59)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.CoreRenderKitFactory.getRenderKit(CoreRenderKitFactory.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderKits(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:159)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:340)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    ... 25 more
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/ADFMinimal_ViewController_webapp1] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager getFactory
SEVERE: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
Sep 10, 2016 12:43:13 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4920)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4784)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:780)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1069)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I'm stuck in finding a solution for this problem. Can someone give me a clue?

**Additional Details**

- Java Version: 1.6.0_27
- Tomcat version: 6.0.45
- Oracle jDeveloper version: 11.1.1.7.0
- OS: Windows 7

List of all libs in the WEB-INF/lib folder